# Specifying how git will *merge* based on file extension

Tags: git, gitlab, unity3d

## Problem

I am using GitLab to version control a Unity project. I am trying to set up git so that it will use different tools to *merge* based on the file extension. I would like git to use WinMerge as it's *merge* tool for all files except for files I want to use SmartMerge. I do not want git to attempt to automatically merge files I want to use SmartMerge for. Not sure if this is even possible.

#### Solution Attempt

I've added the following to my config file in my local .git folder to setup *git merge*:

```
[merge]
    tool = unityyamlmerge

[mergetool "unityyamlmerge"]
    trustExitCode = false
    cmd = '<path to UnityYAMLMerge>' merge -p "$BASE" "$REMOTE" "$LOCAL" "$MERGED"
[merge]
    tool = winmerge

[mergetool "winmerge"]
    name = WinMerge
    trustExitCode = true
    cmd = '<path to WinMerge>' -u -e -dl \"Local\" -dr \"Remote\" $LOCAL $REMOTE $MERGED
```

And I've added the following to my .attributes file in the top level of my repo to specify what file types to use SmartMerge for:

```
# Unity YAML
*.mat merge=unityyamlmerge eol=lf
*.anim merge=unityyamlmerge eol=lf
*.unity merge=unityyamlmerge eol=lf
*.prefab merge=unityyamlmerge eol=lf
*.physicMaterial2D merge=unityyamlmerge eol=lf
*.physicMaterial merge=unityyamlmerge eol=lf
*.asset merge=unityyamlmerge eol=lf
*.meta merge=unityyamlmerge eol=lf
*.controller merge=unityyamlmerge eol=lf
```

I think part of my confusion lies in how the [section "subsection"] of the config file are used by git. Any guidance greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!